# PGFPlot : Relative positioning of legend according to axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, legend

I am trying to move the legend of a PGFPlot above the top right corner, but using relative positioning like `at={(current axis.above of north east)}` in stead of manually giving a position like `at={(1, 1.02)}`. Would it be possible ?

In the Tikz documentation, there is something like `legend=north outside` but such a syntax seems not to exist within PGFPlots.

Here is a minimal working example :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    every axis legend/.append style = {
        anchor=south east,
        at={(1,1.02)},
        draw=none
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=major, enlarge x limits=false]
        \addplot[domain=-2:2, color=red, samples=50, smooth]{sin(pi*deg(x))};
        \addlegendentry{$\sin(x)$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The only predefined outside position seems to be `legend pos=outer north east`. Look up `legend pos` in the manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  At page 228 of PGFPlots manual (version 1.12.1), in the chapter corresponding to `colorbar right`, there is the use of `at={(parent axis.right of north east)}`. It is not possible to apply that to other objects ?

Comment: `parent axis` seems to apply only for `colorbars`, don't know if anything like that can be applied to the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 anchor=south east,
 at= {(current axis.north east)}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid=major, enlarge x limits=false,
        legend style={
        anchor=south east,
        %cells={anchor=east},
        draw=none,
        at= {(current axis.north east)},
}]
        \addplot[domain=-2:2, color=red, samples=50, smooth]{sin(pi*deg(x))};
        \addlegendentry{$\sin(x)$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is also what I tried, but it does not add a "standard" spacing between the plot axis and its legend. But I understand the answer that no, the syntax does not exist without using some additional commands.
Would it be possible to transfer the problem to the anchor ? My unsuccessful try is the following : `anchor={below of south east}`. I think my confusion comes form the fact that I don't know precisely the different behaviors of a regular node and the legend.

Comment: @Mammouth What do you mean by standard spacing?

Comment: @Mammouth: `anchor=south east,
 at= {(current axis.north east)}` is equivalent of `current axis.above of north east`.

Comment: When using nodes in tikz, it is possible to position them according to another one, i.e. below. It does not make them touch one another. Here, the top right corner corresponds to the anchor.

Comment: @Mammouth: If you mean the vertical separation, it can be adjusted by `inner ysep`. `at` is different from `above`